# My "npm create-react-app" command is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

What should I do? I cannot create a react app using npm and while using npx I do not know why it gives me reportwebvitals.js or something and I need serviceworker.js

The error as an image:

[image: The error as an image]

Comment: 1. You mean `npx create-react-app <name>`; and 2. yes, the service worker was removed from the default template in v4, if you want it use the PWA template.

Comment: npx and npm will both give you the same template, but in any case : npm init react-app my-app is the command for npm

Comment: how to get the servicewroker.js ?

Comment: When you want to show textual information on Stack Overflow, please supply it as text. You can copy the text out of your console and use code formatting. Would you edit your question?

Answer (score 1):

use the npx, not npm

```
npx create-react-app myreact
```

it's will work well..